# Card Counts for Expert and Goblins Versus Gnomes Packs

Tags: hearthstone

The Hearthstone arena now only gives only Goblins Versus Gnomes packs as rewards.

I've noticed that I keep getting the same cards over and over. So I got curious:

How many collectible Goblins Versus Gnomes cards are there, and how many collectible Expert cards are there?

Comment: What do you mean under "base deck cards" in GvG ?

Comment: @666nordless666 I was hoping to get the number of possible collectible cards that I could get from a base pack and the number of possible collectible cards I could get from a GvG pack. It seems like the possibilities for GvG packs must be smaller. I actually got *two of the  same card* in one GvG pack!

Comment: That frequently happens, in Expert as well as GvG packs. They're called *Expert* by the way, *Basic* are the truly free ones you can unlock by leveling heroes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 505 collectible cards in Hearthstone. A breakdown of these by set is:

- 382 Collectible cards in the Expert set.
- 123 Collectible cards in Goblins vs Gnomes.

Comment: Wow I guess that makes sense that I keep seeing the same cards from Goblins Versus Gnomes packs then.

Comment: Does "base set" include the Basic and Expert sets? You might want to break those down since the method of acquisition is different.

Comment: I think when he means "collectable" he is excluding soul bound cards, seeing you do not need to collect them.

Comment: @scenia Basic sets are not generally considered 'collectible'.

Comment: You unlock the basic set by playing the class, if you haven't played it you don't get the basics... so it might be slightly 'collectable'

Comment: By that logic, Naxxramas cards are also not collectible since they're statically unlocked by completing the Adventure and are soulbound. And the point stands that the "base set" is called "Expert".

Comment: @Waterseas I agree with [scenia](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/68585/scenia) you probably should remove the Naxxramas listing since those are soulbound.

Comment: @JonathanMee Fair enough, tis a good point, fixed both issues.